# Add PHP code after title in single post pages?

Tags: filters, wp-title

I tried to add PHP code after the post title in single post pages by adding a filter to `functions.php`, but this did not work:

```
function theme_slug_filter_the_content( $content ) {
    $custom_content = 'MY CODES';
    $custom_content .= $content;
    return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'theme_slug_filter_the_content' );
```

Comment: You are saying *Add a php code after **post title** in post pages*, have a look at [`the_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) hook.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `the_title` filter, not `the_content`.
Also make sure you have `the_title()` function somewhere in your single post page.
Here is the code:

```
function theme_slug_filter_the_content( $title ) {
    $custom_title  = 'MY CODES';
    $custom_title  .= $title ;
    return $custom_title ;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'theme_slug_filter_the_content' );
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below code that you needs to write in content.php file

```
if ( is_single() ) :
    the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
else :
    the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' );
endif;
```

Here after  Or  you can add your code.

I hope your single.php file load template function call this content.php file. you can check this on twentyfifteen theme also that comes with default wordpress installation.